# populate text box from MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to Query a database and then populate a textbox input with the result.

I'm trying

Date Called:

```
   <td>
      <?php 
         $selectedSPK=$_POST['SPKSelect'];
        $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
        $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];

if ($selectedSPK)

{
    $Call1query = "SELECT  Call1 FROM Data WHERE SPKCustNo  = '$selectedSPK' ";

$Call1result = mysql_query($Call1query);


 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($Call1result) ){
    $Call1 = $row["$Call1Result"];

    }

}
?>
    <input type="text" name="Call1" id="Call1" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $Call1) ); ?>"/></td>
```

But getting nothing out, where am I going wrong, Text inputs seem tricky to populate!

Thankyou!

Comment: You can't do this... `$Call1 = $row["$Call1Result"];`... Give the field names in `$row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$Call1 = $row["$Call1"];
```

with

```
$Call1 = $row["Call1"];
```

Answer (score 2):

use instead

```
$Call1 = $row["Call1"];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou, will mark as answer as soon as the timer lets me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here change

```
$Call1 = $row["$Call1Result"];
```

to

```
$Call1 = $row['Call1'];   //here column name comes not variable name
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<td>
  <?php 
     $selectedSPK=$_POST['SPKSelect'];
    $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
    $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];

if ($selectedSPK)

{
 $Call1query = "SELECT  Call1 FROM Data WHERE SPKCustNo  = '$selectedSPK' ";

$Call1result = mysql_query($Call1query);


 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($Call1result) ){
$Call1 = $row["Call1"];

}

}?>

<input type="text" name="Call1" id="Call1" value="<?php echo( htmlspecialchars( $Call1) ); ?>"/></td>
```